# Gym Environment Creation

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I'm new to Openai and Gym. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and have all the dependencies installed with me. I'm unable to figure out the sequence of execution of commands for the construction of a 'new' gym environment.

Please refer to https://github.com/hackthemarket/gym-trading.

When I'm trying to implement the same on my own, it displays:

```
raise error.UnregisteredEnv('No registered env with id: {}'.format(id))
gym.error.UnregisteredEnv: No registered env with id: trading-v0
```

Please explain me the correct sequence of execution of files for this example.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install this environment with the setup.py

`pip install -e .`